# How to edit specific sections of a php code using javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello guys I was wondering if I could remove 2 specific sections of this code using JavaScript...

**Original Code:**

```
<div class="chat-column">
    <div class="chat-column-head chat-container"></div>
    <div class="chat-wrapper chat-column-body chat-container"></div>
    <div class="chat-column-head mediapost-container"></div>
    <div class="chat-wrapper chat-column-body mediapost-container"></div>
    <!--

     Ad section 

    -->
    <!--

     End Ad section 

    -->
    <div class="chat-column-head"></div>
    <div>
        <ul class="mediapost-list clearfix"></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-column-head"></div>
    <div class="related-posts chat-column-body">
        <ul class="mediapost-list clearfix"></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-column-head"></div>
    <div class="related-videos chat-column-body"></div>
```

I'd like to remove this section

```
<div class="chat-column-head"></div>
<div class="related-posts chat-column-body">
    <ul class="mediapost-list clearfix"></ul>
</div>
```

*and*

```
<div class="chat-column-head"></div>
<div>
    <ul class="mediapost-list clearfix"></ul>
</div>
```

Would it be easier to get rid of the `ul` listing and keep the titles even though it would be horrible to keep?

Comment: JavaScript is run in the client (the browser) and generally has no contact with server-side code. You can remove elements dynamically from a rendered page, however.

Answer (score 0):

First, Your code has nothing to do with PHP.

Second,

```
var names = ["chat-column-head",
             "related-posts chat-column-body",
             "chat-column-head"]

var cch = document.getElementByClassName("chat-column-head")[0]
cch.parentNode.removeChild(cch.nextSibling)
for(var i=0; i<names.length; i++) {
  var element = document.getElementByClassName(names[i])[0]
  element.parentNode.removeChild(element)
}
```

Comment: assuming what the asker posted is exactly what they have and exactly the parts they want to discard... it might be better to start document.getElementsByTagName("ul")

Answer (score 0):

You cannot edit php code with javascript, PHP runs before the page gets to the browser. However the code you posted is HTML and yes you can remove it with Javascript. You would need to assign an event with the task, probably either on page load or a button, and then write a function which removes that element.